# rails combining data from 2 different sources in an html table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I get data from two external services:

```
@list =  ExternalService.get_list
ids =  @list.map { |member| meber.id }

insurances = ExternalService2.get_insurance

# Get insurance information for each of the ids.
@coverages = insurances.map { |insurance| InsurancePresenter.new(insurance) }

/ In the view
- @list.each do |member|
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td= member.name
      %td= member.age

      / This is the part where I need to get information from the other service
      %td
        - @coverages.each |coverage|
          / method name from the presenter
          = coverage.name
```

Obvisouly the last part of my code is incorrect because it would print all the coverages on each row.

I was wondering if there is a quick way to combine the 2 and display them in the app.
If it was a database request it would have been a simple join.

Comment: Are coverages and list related?  If it's easy to do in a join, it'll likely be easy here.  Just need an association to work with.

Comment: @Swards. Its not related. Like I mentioned. Its not hitting a database directly. it is external service which gives us back json.

Comment: I see - is there any relation between the two external services?  How do you know that the list and coverages are related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to start a count and iterate for each member, and use the count to display each coverage from the coverages array. Sorry don't know HAML, but here is the general idea.

/ In the view

```
count = -1
- @list.each do |member|
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td= member.name
      %td= member.age
      count+=1
      / This is the part where I need to get information from the other service
      %td
        - @coverages[count].name
```

Comment: Is the syntax -@coverages[count].name correct. I am getting an undefined method [] error

Comment: Hmmm, well assuming coverages is an array containing coverages objects, then you should be able to do this.